# ListView Xamarin not Binding when adding item

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I Am working with a ListView Control in XF application. My XAML Code looks like this.

```
    <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding RechargeList}" HasUnevenRows="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextCell Text="{Binding Path=SelectedParkingID}" TextColor="Red" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

While my code behind looks like

```
    private ObservableCollection<Recharge> _RechargeList = new ObservableCollection<Recharge>();
    public ObservableCollection<Recharge> RechargeList
    {
        get
        {
            return _RechargeList;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _RechargeList, value);
        }

    }
```

And I add Items to Collection in DelegateCommand Event

```
RechargeList.Add(new Recharge() { SelectedParkingIDParkingID = ParkingID, RechargeAmount = double.Parse(RechargeAmount), BalanceAmount = 10 });
```

However, the Listview fails to refresh. Could some one help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo

```
<TextCell Text="{Binding Path=SelectedParkingID}" TextColor="Red" />
```

Should be

```
<TextCell Text="{Binding Path=SelectedParkingIDParkingID }" TextColor="Red" />
```

based on what your model looks like. If you try to bind to a property that doesn't exist, it fails softly. So you're adding an item, but the `TextCell` doesn't render since it has no content.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your class.

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 // boiler-plate
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null) handler(this, new   PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
    field = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    return true;
}

   // props
  private string name;
  public string Name
  {
    get { return name; }
    set { SetField(ref name, value, "Name"); }
  }
}
```

Each property is then just something like:

```
private string name;
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set { SetField(ref name, value, "Name"); }
}
```